# Java : Parameter does not exist as a named parameter

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

here is my HQL Query :

```
buffer = new StringBuilder();
buffer.append("SELECT R ");
buffer.append("FROM " + getEntityClassName() + " R ");
buffer.append("LEFT JOIN E.debit D ");
buffer.append("LEFT JOIN E.etablissement E ");
buffer.append("WHERE D.id = :idDebit ");
buffer.append("ORDER BY R.periodeDebut DESC ");

hqlQuery = session.createQuery(buffer.toString());
hqlQuery.setInteger("idDebit", idDebit);
```

I got this error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter idDebit does not exist as a named parameter in [SELECT R FROM fr.gouv.finances.douane.gimt.dao.base.commun.impl.DebitReventeDaoImpl R LEFT JOIN E.debit D LEFT JOIN E.etablissement E WHERE D.id = :idDebit ORDER BY R.periodeDebut DESC ]
```

When i change the **setInteger** by `setParameter("idDebit", idDebit)`, i got this error :

```
org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [idDebit]
```

if i change it also like this :

```
WHERE D.id = ?
setParameter(0, idDebit)
```

i got this error :

```
org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 1
```

Thank's for your help

Comment: I've tried it, i got the same error : `code`Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 2

Comment: fr.gouv.finances.douane.gimt.dao.base.commun.impl.DebitReventeDaoImpl.. is that an entity? If so please add the impl code

Comment: Thank's @MaciejKowalski, the Entity is DebitReventeMod, i change it and it works

Comment: Cool, glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

```
setParameter(0, idDebit)
```

Change to

```
setParameter(1, idDebit)
```

Comment: I got the same error :
`code` Position beyond number of declared ordinal parameters. Remember that ordinal parameters are 1-based! Position: 2 `code`